# All my segues converted to Modally. How to restart original condition

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I had an app in swift with five view controllers an navigation bar working properly in all of them. But I didn't  check the "Is initial View Controller" from any View Controller in Storyboard. But some reason the app knows who was the first view Controller and everything is ok.

Then I decided to check "Is initial View Controller" for my first View Controller.

All of a sudden ALL MY SEGUES were converted automatically do MODALLY view !! I lost ALL navigation in ALL view controllers !!

Then I uncheck "Is initial View Controller" but no way.. I never restored the original condition

I almost loosing my whole job for months in this app !! Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where to check "is initial view controller", you must to check "is initial view controller" in corresponding Navigation Controller as Storyboard entry point and NOT viewcontroller.